# リダイレクトがうまくいきません。

Tags: php

HTMLメール本文のリンクからログインフォームにリダイレクトさせたいのですが、うまく行かず詰まっています。どなたかアドバイスを頂けないでしょうか。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
404/The requested URL /kento/register/login.php was not found on this server.
```

**ソースコード**

```
<?php

if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    ini_set('display_errors',1);//画面にエラーを表示
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    session_start();

    $firstname='';
    $lastname='';
    $email='';
    $phone='';
    $birthdate='';
    $username='';
    $password='';

    if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_post['email'])
            && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['birthdate']) && isset($_POST['username'])
            && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $_SESSION["USER"] = 'USER';
        header("Location:https:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kento/php/microblog/login.php");
        exit;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        echo "Please check the Email";
    } else {
        echo "Your Email is invalid , please check your Email address again";
    }

    $dsn ='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=microblog';
    $user ='root';
    $password ='root';
    //$USER = $FILES['firstname']['lastname']['email']['phone']['birthdate']['username']['password'];
    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(firstname,lastname,email,phone,username,password)
                VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :phone, :username, :password)");
        $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
                    ':lastname'  => $_POST['lastname'],
                    ':email'     => $_POST['email'],
                    ':phone'     => $_POST['phone'],
                    ':username'  => $_POST['username'],
                    ':password'  => $_POST['password']
                    ));

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die ('error:'.$e->getMessage());
    }

    $to = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = 'Email vertification';
    $message = '
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>sending link</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <a href="https://localhost:8080/MAMP/htdocs/kento/register/login.php">Click this link to activate your account!</a>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
    $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<h2>Register your information</h2>

<form method="POST" action="register.php">
Fastname:<input type="text" name="firstname"><br><br>
Lastname:<input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>
Email Adrress:<input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
Phone Number:<input type="text" name="phone"><br><br>
Birth Date:<input type="text" name="birthdate"><br><br>
Username:<input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
Password:<input type="text" name="password"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

routesファイルでルート設定をしてあげる事で自己解決いたしました。

```
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'home'));
Router::connect('/signup', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'signup'));
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/profile', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'profile'));
Router::connect('/search', array('controller' => 'Follows', 'action' => 'search'));
Router::connect('/logout', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'logout'));
```